# Specifying image size used in template the_content

Tags: query-posts, the-content, images

I have a template that is used to display all posts. It uses `query_posts` with a set of `$args` that I specify. The template uses `the_content` to output the content of each post (text and images)

I want all images in the template output to be shown as 'medium' size on the template-generated page, no matter how the images were stored in the post. I don't want to change the content in the database, just the output that is generated with my custom template.

Comment: Do you mean just featured image or all the images in the post either uploaded or referenced by an URL?

Comment: @bravokeyl Since the template outputs all posts, no pagination, etc, then any the_content that contains pictures or galleries needs to have the pictures set at 'medium'. Thanks.